# GraphQL implementation Java

Tags: java, rest, graphql

I am having 5 rest API's(java) with different endpoint URL,and each have different request,response format.So I have combined them as a single API with a common JSON complex request and response as a key value pair structure.

Now T found recently about GraphQL and interested to fit it in my requirement,
I have done analysis on that and want to know how well I Could implement some of my questions:

1) Can we implement complex rest API service(post) in    GRAPHQL?(while googling,got only for simple get method.Also is there    only for node/javascript)

2) Is there any framework for  java    based graphQL implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) Can we implement complex rest API service(post) in GRAPHQL?(while googling,got only for simple get method.Also is there only for node/javascript)

Since you say you did your analysis about GraphQL, I'm assuming that by "implement complex REST API server (POST) in GraphQL", you meant how you can expose the functionality of REST API through GraphQL. Yes, you can do that by using GraphQL mutations. In your mutation implementation (resolve function), you'll invoke the REST POST operations.

[swapi-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/swapi-graphql) is an interesting project that wraps [Star Wars REST API](https://swapi.co/).

> 2) Is there any framework for java based graphQL implementation?

Check out Java section of [awesome-graphql](https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-graphql#lib-java). The Java GraphQL library doesn't seem to be well-maintained though.

Answer (score 5):

Question 1) is answered in the other answer.

Question 2) Java Implementation:

- [graphql-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java) is a Java implementation for GraphQL.
- [graphql-java-annotations](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations) is a Java Library build on graphql-java.

Sample Code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphQLObjectType queryType = newObject()
            .name("helloWorldQuery")
            .field(newFieldDefinition()
                .type(GraphQLString)
                .name("hello")
                .staticValue("world"))
            .build();

        GraphQLSchema schema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
            .query(queryType)
            .build();

        GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();

        Map<String, Object> result = graphQL.execute("{hello}").getData();
        System.out.println(result);
        // Prints: {hello=world}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some library as an answer. At least demonstrate how the library solves the problem in the answer itself.

Comment: What's still wrong with my answer for getting more downvotes?

Comment: I upvoted you bro.  The above comment is completely irrelevant.

Comment: This response presents client side usage. The question is about exposing server-side endpoint.